# Menu using AngularJS

Tags: json, angularjs

I need to create menu using AngularJS based on JSON file that looks like:

```
{
    "menu": [{
        "id": "1",
        "name": "Movies",
        "parent_id": "0"
    }, {
        "id": "2",
        "name": "Trailers",
        "parent_id": "1"
    }, {
        "id": "3",
        "name": "Action And Adventure",
        "parent_id": "1"
    }, {
        "id": "4",
        "name": "Animation",
        "parent_id": "3"
    }, {
        "id": "5",
        "name": "Kids",
        "parent_id": "0"
    }]
}
```

The list should looks like:

- Movies

  - Trailers
  - Action And Adventure

    - Animation
- Kids

I really don't know how to create this, any help would be great.

Comment: Your JSON really doesnt match what you're trying to accomplish

Comment: Do you have any control over the JSON data structure? Ideally it should mirror the list you're trying to create.

Comment: Yes I have. Is it better to create a tag "children" inside parent instead of using "parent_id" on child links.

Answer (score 0):

Please go through this [link](http://ngmodules.org/modules/angular.treeview), you just need to have the tree structure in angularjs. Go through this link, Hope this would help!